# Вставка кода Assembler-a

Tags: ассемблер, eclipse, c++

Мне необходимо выставить значение `0xFFFE` по адресу `0x80002040`, я написал для этого такой код:

```
  __asm
    {
      mov r0, 0xFFFE        Строка 1
      mov #0x80002040, r0   Строка 2
      mov r0, 0xFFFE
    }
```

Всё это делается в Eclipse для микропроцессора NT2000.
Я получаю в ответ при компиляции:

> warning  #1267-D: Implicit physical
>   register R0 should be defined as a
>   variable
>
> error  #1093: Must be a modifiable
>   lvalue

Предупреждение приходит на строку 1, а ошибка на строку 2.

Comment: Попробуйте

    mov [#0x80002040], r0

Comment: попробовал, но теперь другая ошибка на ту же строку 2: 
Expected a register expression

Comment: А символ '#' это что?

    mov [0x80002040], r0 
 
Так не катит?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, погуглил, похоже, вам нужна команда str вместо mov. Насколько я понял, у arm процессоров команда mov работает только с регистрами общего назначения, но не с адресами в памяти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уже заработало, необходимо было сделать так:

```
  mov   r6, #0x80002040 
  mov   r7, #0xFFFE
  str r7,[r6]
  mov   r6, #0x80002040
```

Символ "#" значит, что это 16-ричное число, проблема была в том, что нельзя было переслать напрямую в память, необходимо было из регистра в регистр, который хранит память.

**Обновление**

И ещё кое-что забыл: необходимо было перед вставкой кода ассемблера объявить 2 переменные типа int, r6 и r7, т.к. ассемблер не поймёт названия этих регистров без их объявления, а на самом деле проц будет использовать какие-то свои регистры, у которых название может быть любое.